# How to deploy a web application on Jetty

Tags: eclipse, command-prompt

I create a war file , then i executed in eclipse, like [described](http://www.enavigo.com/2008/08/29/deploying-a-web-application-to-jetty/#more-208) here.

I don't know configure the context path, how can I run the war file?

Comment: How do you create your war file?

Comment: i create one web application in eclipse , then i use export war option using war file created , but i don't know how to configure ,

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can run your webapp using `Jetty` Server

1. Configure jetty server using [Jetty_WTP_Plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty_WTP_Plugin) and run webapp within eclipse
2. Download stand alone jetty server from [Jetty Distributions from Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/downloads.php)

If you use second option, you need to create war file keep war file interface /webapps folder.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used jetty but I know that its quite similar to tomcat. Just place your war file (say foo.war) in webapps directory; Start jetty by the following command in

```
java -jar start.jar
```

and hit `http://localhost:8080/foo` in your browser

By the way the tutorial you're using is quite an old one and may not work for jetty 8 or 9